# Is the STM32 DMA destination address restricted?

Tags: stm32, stm32f4, dma

I'm using a `stm32f446` and would like to use the `TIM4_CH2` request with the `DMA1` in `Memory-to-peripheral` mode to transfer data from an array to the `ODR` (output data register) of a GPIO port.

For some reason it only works with *some* destination addresses (and not with the `&GPIOx->ODR` address), even through the [reference manual](http://www2.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/reference_manual/4d/ed/bc/89/b5/70/40/dc/DM00135183.pdf/files/DM00135183.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.DM00135183.pdf) states at *9.3.6 Source, Destination and transfer modes*:

> Both source and destination transfers can address peripherals and memories in the entire 4 GB area, at addresses comprised between 0x0000 0000 and 0xFFFF FFFF

Is there any further restriction I should be aware off?

```
HAL_TIM_OC_Start(&htim4, TIM_CHANNEL_2);


uint16_t buffer[] = {1,2,3,4,5};
uint32_t dataLength = sizeof(buffer)/sizeof(buffer[0]);
uint32_t srcAddress = (uint32_t) buffer;
//uint32_t dstAddress = (uint32_t) &(TIM4->CCR2); // Works
//uint32_t dstAddress = (uint32_t) &(TIM4->CCR4); // Works
//uint32_t dstAddress = (uint32_t) &(TIM5->CCR4); // Doesn't work
uint32_t dstAddress = (uint32_t) &(GPIOC->ODR); // Doesn't work


HAL_DMA_Start_IT(&hdma_tim4_ch2, srcAddress, dstAddress, dataLength);
__HAL_TIM_ENABLE_DMA(&htim4, TIM_DMA_CC2);
```

The DMA initializing code:

```
hdma_tim4_ch2.Instance = DMA1_Stream3;
hdma_tim4_ch2.Init.Channel = DMA_CHANNEL_2;
hdma_tim4_ch2.Init.Direction = DMA_MEMORY_TO_PERIPH;
hdma_tim4_ch2.Init.PeriphInc = DMA_PINC_DISABLE;
hdma_tim4_ch2.Init.MemInc = DMA_MINC_ENABLE;
hdma_tim4_ch2.Init.PeriphDataAlignment = DMA_PDATAALIGN_HALFWORD;
hdma_tim4_ch2.Init.MemDataAlignment = DMA_MDATAALIGN_HALFWORD;
hdma_tim4_ch2.Init.Mode = DMA_NORMAL;
hdma_tim4_ch2.Init.Priority = DMA_PRIORITY_LOW;
hdma_tim4_ch2.Init.FIFOMode = DMA_FIFOMODE_DISABLE;
HAL_DMA_Init(&hdma_tim4_ch2);

__HAL_LINKDMA(htim_base,hdma[TIM_DMA_ID_CC2],hdma_tim4_ch2);
```

Timer configuration:

```
TIM_ClockConfigTypeDef sClockSourceConfig;
TIM_MasterConfigTypeDef sMasterConfig;
TIM_OC_InitTypeDef sConfigOC;

htim4.Instance = TIM4;
htim4.Init.Prescaler = 0;
htim4.Init.CounterMode = TIM_COUNTERMODE_UP;
htim4.Init.Period = 72;
htim4.Init.ClockDivision = TIM_CLOCKDIVISION_DIV1;
HAL_TIM_Base_Init(&htim4);

sClockSourceConfig.ClockSource = TIM_CLOCKSOURCE_INTERNAL;
HAL_TIM_ConfigClockSource(&htim4, &sClockSourceConfig);

HAL_TIM_OC_Init(&htim4);

sMasterConfig.MasterOutputTrigger = TIM_TRGO_OC2REF;
sMasterConfig.MasterSlaveMode = TIM_MASTERSLAVEMODE_DISABLE;
HAL_TIMEx_MasterConfigSynchronization(&htim4, &sMasterConfig);

sConfigOC.OCMode = TIM_OCMODE_TOGGLE;
sConfigOC.Pulse = 0;
sConfigOC.OCPolarity = TIM_OCPOLARITY_HIGH;
sConfigOC.OCFastMode = TIM_OCFAST_DISABLE;
HAL_TIM_OC_ConfigChannel(&htim4, &sConfigOC, TIM_CHANNEL_2);
```

Comment: backing out my comments to let you focus on the problem...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The DMA addresses are restricted by the memory architecture (See Chapter 2, *Memory and bus architecture* in the [reference manual](http://www2.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/reference_manual/4d/ed/bc/89/b5/70/40/dc/DM00135183.pdf/files/DM00135183.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.DM00135183.pdf)). The following figure from the reference manual illustrates the problem of using DMA1:

[image: stm32 memory architecture]

The problem can be solved by simply using DMA2 (and another request according to the DMA2 request mapping table). E.g. DMA2 with the Timer 1 channel 1 request will just work fine:

```
HAL_TIM_OC_Start(&htim1, TIM_CHANNEL_1);

uint16_t buffer[] = {0,1,2,4,8,16,32,64,128,256,512,1024,2048};
uint32_t dataLength = sizeof(buffer)/sizeof(buffer[0]);
uint32_t srcAddress = (uint32_t) buffer;
uint32_t dstAddress = (uint32_t) &(GPIOC->ODR);

HAL_DMA_Start_IT(&hdma_tim1_ch1, srcAddress, dstAddress, dataLength);
__HAL_TIM_ENABLE_DMA(&htim1, TIM_DMA_CC1);
```